# gradientFunctions not find op_name: SplitV error i tesorflow.net C# in the GRU unit

Tags: c#

error crash "gradientFunctions not find op_name: SplitV"   appears when LSTM layer is replaced  by equvivalent GRU layer. For tesorflow.net C#   in the GRU unit

model.add(keras.layers.GRU(units: numberOfHiddenUnits, kernel_initializer: "glorot_uniform", return_sequences: false));  // CRASHES 'gradientFunctions not find op_name: SplitV'